# How to awk the "df -Pm" command to get FS names that have more then 90% the FS usage?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get the names of all disks with at least 90% usage, using this oneliner:

```
df -Pm | awk '+$5 >= 90 {print}'
```

But it doesn't show the "100% usage" case, I need to grep for "100%". Why doesn't it work correctly?

Comment: what version of awk are you running?

Comment: I just `dd`'d my disk usage so I had both 100% used on one fs and between 90 and 100 on another and I got both reported. Used your exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Could you give us an example output from `df -Pm` ? I'm sure most of us don't have 100% or their disk space used ;)

i just tested by hacking up my `df`'s output and your `awk` part seems to be fine.

```
$ cat /tmp/1 | awk '+$5 >= 90 {print}'
tmpfs                        1978         1      1978     101% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        1978         1      1977     100% /run
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is the percentage sign, which probably turns the >= into a string comparison. Add 0 to $5 before doing the comparison, this way you force $5 to be interpreted as a number:

```
df -P | awk '0 + $5 >= 90 { print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slightly alternate approach. A little math never hurt anyone.

```
df -Pml | tail -n +2 | awk '{if ($4/$2 < 0.1) print $1,"is getting full."}'
```

This will calculate whether the filesystem is less than 10% free (which is actually how df displays it, even though the column is labeled "Used", and the `-l` prints only local filesystems). Throwing in `tail -n +2` skips the header.